# How to not reset an index when app restarts swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am fairly new to coding, so I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am creating an app that cycles through items in an array at the press of a button, using an index that the button ads 1 to every time it's pressed. The problem is, that whenever I restart the app, the index resets to 0, and I have to cycle through all of the items again. 
Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
var currentIndexCount = 0 //my index

class PromptViewController: UIViewController {

let prompts = ["a", "b","c","d","e","f","g","h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]  


@IBOutlet var PromptLbl: UILabel!  //the label that displays items from the array



@IBAction func GivePrompt(_ sender: UIButton)  //my button
{   
    if currentIndexCount < prompts.count {
     PromptLbl.text = prompts[currentIndexCount]
     currentIndexCount = currentIndexCount + 1
    }

    PromptLbl.numberOfLines  =   3
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) for this.

Save the string after you increment the value in your button method:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(currentIndexCount, forKey: "index")
```

Retrieve the string in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller:

```
currentIndexCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: “index”)
```

This method will return `0` if the key does not exist (e.g. on the first use).

---

As a side note, it is good practice to start your variable and function names with lowercase letters. Uppercase letters at the start should be reserved for *types*, like the definition of a `class` or `struct`. Instances should have a lowercase letter at the start.